# reputation change when asker change accepted answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When asker change accepted answer to another answer, reputation of answerer will change (-15) but he/she will not know the reason.

I think it should notify to answerer of the previous accepted answer.

Comment: It will say under the "reputation" tab -"15" and I believe the comment next to it will say "unaccepted". I'm not sure what exactly it says and I can't find an example right now but if you lose 15 rep on one answer then it will be obvious what it was from

Comment: @codeMagic is right, you can, in your reputation tab, see 'unaccepted answer' and the link to the said answer with along with your reputation change

Comment: There's only ever one reason, the OP got a better answer.  Focus on the title of the notification box, it says "Achievements".  Losing rep is not an achievement, anybody can do that.  It is a feel-good box, omitting bad news was quite intentional.  A lot less drama that way.  Simply look at the Reputation tab in your profile.

Answer (score 6):

A user is able to see reputation changes (including unaccepted answers) in the reputation history tab of their profile. An unaccept will appear like this in the history:

[image: Unaccepted]

From this entry, you are able to go visit the question. Use that link to see why your answer was unaccepted by reading the newly accepted answer.

As Hans Passant mentioned in his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290708/reputation-change-when-asker-change-accepted-answer#comment178921_290708), such a notification is not how the top bar functions. It's purpose is to show you positive things that have happened to your account. Losing reputation is not a positive.

Comment: I remember reading that last part based on Hans Passant comment somewhere but cannot get the link of this faq / meta post back, maybe you could help ?

Comment: @b.enoit.be Here's a good one on MSE, where the [feature request to show negative reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements) was declined.

Comment: ah, my answer is accept and unaccept in one day, so I can't see this notify in my profile @Andy